# Как суммировать полученные числа из "countRandom" с "thisCount", чтобы при каждом вызове функции, бралось новое число?

Tags: javascript

```js
    function countPeople() {
        var thisCount = 100;
        var countRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        thisCount = thisCount + countRandom;
        console.log(thisCount);
    }
    setInterval(() => countPeople(), 1000);
```

То есть, за первый вызов функции "countRandom" получилось число "16" и это число суммируется с числом, которое в переменной "thisCount". Когда функция вызывается втором раз, то число должно браться из переменной "thisCount" уже не "100", а "116" и так до бесконечности...

Comment: А сейчас что не так?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Дописал в вопросе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Решил проблему по своему, но вдруг есть какой-нибудь другой вариант, может более правильный.
Сейчас добавлю ответ в вопрос...

Answer (score 2):

Оно?

```js
function countPeople(_thisCount) {
    let thisCount = _thisCount;
    
    return () => {
        let countRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        thisCount = thisCount + countRandom;  
        console.log(countRandom, thisCount);
    }         
}

let countPeopleF = countPeople(100);
setInterval(() => countPeopleF(), 1000);
```

Также в зависимости от задачи может быть достаточно переменную вынести за функцию и передать её?

```js
function countPeople(count) {
    let countRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    
    return count + countRandom;    
}

let initialValue = 100;
let sum = initialValue;

setInterval(() => {    
    sum = countPeople(sum);
    console.log(sum);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: "Также в зависимости от задачи может быть достаточно переменную вынести за функцию и передать её?"

Как раз так и сделал ))

Comment: @roderann да, просто если это не задача про замыкания, то и смысла нет... Единственное наверное при выносе как переменной, стоит возвращать значение из функции, а внутри функции НЕ ИЗМЕНЯТЬ текущую переменную. Потому что это неочевидное поведение и других разрабов может запутать и ввести в недоумение

Comment: @roderann что-то примерное как во втором варианте

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему сам, но может у кого-то будет более разумное решение или просто другие варианты (интересно будет посмотреть).
Я просто вынес переменую `var thisCount = 100;` перед функцией.

```js
var thisCount = 100;
    function countPeople() {
        var countRandom = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
        thisCount = thisCount + countRandom;
        console.log(thisCount);
    }
setInterval(() => countPeople(), 1000);
```